# IIS7 ASP.NET connection string override

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7, .net-4.0

I am trying to deploy a ASP .NET website on IIS7.

The dev version has connection string like this:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=localhost,1533;Network Library=dbmssocn;Database=Leads_DB1;Connection Timeout=15;Packet Size=4096; Integrated Security=no;User ID=localdbuser;Password=Pa55w0rd!; Encrypt=no;"/>

<!--DEVELOPMENT DATABASE -->
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=localhost,1533;Network Library=dbmssocn;Database=Mail_Development;Connection Timeout=15;Packet Size=4096; Integrated Security=no;User ID=localdbuser;Password=Pa55w0rd!; Encrypt=no;"/>
<add key="ConnectionStringCRM" value="Data Source=localhost,1533;Network Library=dbmssocn;Database=CRM_MAIL_QUEUE;Connection Timeout=15;Packet Size=4096; Integrated Security=no;User ID=localdbuser;Password=Pa55w0rd!; Encrypt=no;"/>
</appSettings>
```

Now when I create a new connection string using IIS manager connection string dialog, I need to provide a name for the connection and it creates something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Leads_DB1" 
connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Leads_DB1;Integrated Security=no;User ID=localdbuser;Password=Pa55w0rd!; Encrypt=no;"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Problem is in both cases I am not getting DB connection from the App.

Is there any way I can make the Dev version work?

I am afraid, if I use the default config IIS generates, then it would require a major code change at every point there is a DB call.

So, is there any simpler way to do these modifications?

Answer (score 0):

One standard way of accomplishing this is using web.config transformations. You would set the default connection string in your web.config (that will be used in development) and transform the connection string when you deploy to qa/production (supplying the qa or prod connection string.)

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental difference between connectionString and appSettings:

They look for different things. In .NET 2.0 and above:

A connectionString object is an XML node that has specific attributes to set; and semantically it refers to a database connection string.

For instance, a connectionString looks like the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="LocalSqlServer"
      connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

You'll notice it has a few different attributes:

- name
- connectionString : This has a specific string inside of it, it needs an Initial Catalog, a security mechanism (in this case Integrated Security
- providerName

Whereas appSettings is just a user-defined Key-value pair that allows you to... well... set application settings. It can be anything:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Mom" value="Your"/>
  <add key="UseCache" value="True"/>
  <add key="MapsKey" value="1234567890-AA"/>
  <add key="SMTPServer" value="smtp.peterkellner.net"/>
</appSettings>
```

you can fine more infromation at http://peterkellner.net/2008/02/23/webconfigbestpractice/